# Как реализовывать функции MSBuild в .NET6?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-6

Пример учебного кода.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Text="First message" Importance="high"></Message>
</Target>
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Text="Second message" Importance="high"></Message>
</Target>
```

Здравствуйте. Возник вопрос про MSBuild. Если отредактировать .cproj XML, и проект в .NET Framework. Тут всё работает ожидаемо, и выводится сообщение в окно сборки. В .NET 6 это не работает. Я не пойму присутствует этот инструмент в .NET 6 или нет, и как там решается этот вопрос?

Comment: попробуйте указывать разные Targets как тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2022 у меня оно начало выдавать сообщения, но как оно работает и какой правильный порядок и хз

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо. Суть в том что если указать у самого проекта <Project InitialTargets ="таргет1;таргет2"> Таргеты начинают работать. Но насколько я понимаю, они отработают до сборки. А меня интересует в первую очередь как до, так и после. Буду сейчас подробнее изучать структуру.

Comment: `<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Message Text="First message" Importance="high"></Message>
    <Message Text="Second message" Importance="high"></Message>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Message Text="Third message" Importance="high"></Message>
  </Target>`

Comment: Можете посмотреть в сторону [Cake](https://cakebuild.net/) и [Nuke](https://nuke.build/), если вам нужны продвинутые системы сборки. В обоих код пишется на C#.

Comment: Спасибо. Ознакомлюсь с этими системами.